# Nuance and current-ness of "ぼくとお茶しませんか"

Tags: meaning

I heard the phrase of "ぼくとお茶しませんか" from a rather odd [Japan Times article](http://www.japantimes.co.jp/life/2011/10/17/language/desperately-seeking-the-lost-art-of-nanpa) by a presumably Japanese woman called Kaori Shoji. It's also mentioned elsewhere, such as [in a native speaker's blog about Japanese](http://onephrasejapanese.blogspot.com.au/2014/03/the-word-of-today-would-you-mind-having.html).

It literally means "Won't you have green tea with me?", but there's two things I don't know.

What venue is implied by the phrase? Is it implied to be a public venue such as a cafe, or instead is it somebody's home?

Also, is the phrase still used nowadays, or considered out-dated?

Answer (score 6):

ぼくとお茶しませんか is used to *Nanpa* described in that article.

> For men, the favored tactic was nanpa (originally derived from the term nanjyaku, 軟弱 — which means softie) and this amounted to cruising the streets of Shibuya or Shinjuku, looking out for anyone cute who seemed available, and pulling out that famed and lamest of lines: “Bokuto ocha shimasenka? (「ぼくとお茶しませんか」, “Would you like to have a cup of tea with me?”).

If I want to say "Let's take a break" to my friends, I use

- ちょっとお茶しない？
- 休憩しない？

and others.

In this situation, 僕と/私と is left out because it emphasizes "with who?" more than needs. So ぼくとお茶しませんか？ is too politely, and it appears odd.

> Also, is the phrase still used nowadays, or considered out-dated?

As one of *Nanpa* tactic, it maybe still used.

However, I have an impression *Nanpa* is outdated culture...

Answer (score 2):

> What venue is implied

At least traditionally, [Kissa-tens](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%96%AB%E8%8C%B6%E5%BA%97). Kissa-tens used to be cool until around the 80's together with this phrase. Note that "tea" here doesn't mean green tea. Kissa-ten's primary attraction is coffee and to a lesser degree english tea.

> Also, is the phrase still used nowadays, or considered out-dated?

I would say mostly outdated.

Comment: I still hear it a lot in the sense of "let's take a break" - ちょっとお茶しましょうか。 Would you count this as outdated as well?

Comment: If it is outdated, what phrase do they use now?

Comment: I don' think it's outdated. As unarist says, it sounds to me a shy boy is trying to seduce a woman on the street. And we still have many Kissa-ten's, far more than 80's.

Comment: @deceze: No I wouldn't count that as outdated. IMO the idea that Kissa-tens are cool and that you'd take a person who you are attracted to Kissa-ten is what is outdated now.

Comment: @KentaroTomono: Would you use Kissa-tens to do nampa tho? If I were hypothetically had to do nampa, I sure won't choose Kissa-tens. I also don't see people really doing nampa during the day; IMO it tends to happen at night and Karaoke/Izakaya is the usual choice.

Comment: @enno Izakaya is seems to be good, and the boy say like.... "俺いい店知ってるんだけど、一緒にどう？ "

Comment: @Enno Shioji, it's really up to how we categorize Kissa-ten. For example, in Teikoku Hotel, there is a tea room at the top where only a cup of tea needs 1,500 yes = about 13 bucks and there are cigars, cakes etc etc and if you would invite "her" there, then it will cost at least 4,000 yen. 35$ for tea. A nice shot for just tea.